# Cordova OAuth NOT using google/twitter/facebook etc

Tags: cordova, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to write a Cordova/Ionic app that uses OAuth to log into a server. I had been previously using the guide here http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/ , but I now need to use OAuth to carry out the authentication process with a provider that isn't one listed on the page. I've been given a URL, client_id, and some other parameters, and I know I need to make some POST and GET calls, but all the tutorials I've been able to find for OAuth have been using Google and Facebook APIs, or something of that ilk. Any pointers to resources that could help me figure out what I'm supposed to do would be much appreciated, especially if they have example code.

Answer (score 1):

You could try my open source library [**BlackTie.js**](https://www.github.com/divakarmanivel/blacktie).

---

### How to use it :

You can call an oauth service with the function `openOauth(baseurl, tokenurl, clientid, apikey, scope, responsetype, other, callback);`.

The parameters :

- `baseurl` is the url of the service which you want to use.
- `clientid` is the client is you received when you registered for this service.
- `scope` is the space delimited string of scopes you want to use.
- `callback` is the function you want to run when oauth has finished.
- `apikey` is the api key you got when you registered for the service. **(optional)**
- `responsetype` is either token or code based on the service. **(optional)**
- `tokenurl` is the url to get the token from the service if you are using a code type oauth ie. Oauth 1.0. **(optional)**
- `other` is any other information that you would like to append in the queries. **(optional)**

Optional parameters can be set to `null` or `""`.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, due to possible link rot.
This is especially true for links that are already broken.

Comment: https://www.github.com/divakarmanivel/blacktie sorry for the wrong link. @CaringDev I only added the link because the js in the link has what he asked for.

Comment: @DivakarManivel : Personally, I'm totally fine with you providing a link to your own library, but you'll need to add some info on how to actually use the library to solve the problem mentioned in the question. Just saying "here's a library, try it" isn't appreciated here on StackOverflow. Also, people prefer it if you explicitly mention that it is a library that you created yourself. So, you better say "here's MY library" than "here's A library"!

Comment: @John Slegers I'm new to stack overflow so I'm still learning. But thanks for your reply. I have edited the code further for more clarity.

Comment: @DivakarManivel : Please try to make your answers as readable as possible (see my improvements for how to do it). Also, note that people on StackOverflow don't like it when different questions have the exact same answer. If you want to avoid getting downvotes, try to not only give more information but also make your information specific to the question.